# installing grunt using npm manager having connection issues

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm-install

Hey im trying to install Grunt using NPM manager and i seem to be having connection issues  timing out i searched some online. i can hit this URL https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt  just fine it will ask me if i want to save or run GRUNT.JSON and if i cut and paste that URL i will see the contents of that JSON in a gigantic array

```
GEL8953@VALGEL8953L MINGW64 ~/Dev/MillsDashboard/MillsDashboard (master)
$ npm install grunt grunt-cli -g
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli
npm ERR! Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR!     at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
npm ERR!     at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:892:19)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program      
Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "grunt"    
"grunt-cli" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\GEL8953\Dev\MillsDashboard\MillsDashboard
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.13
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.2
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm
```

when executing command "npm i grunt" from project root directory i get the following

```
   GEL8953@VALGEL8953L MINGW64 ~/Dev/MillsDashboard/MillsDashboard (master)
   $ npm i grunt
   npm ERR! Error: Invalid name: "MillsDashbaord"
  npm ERR!     at ensureValidName (C:\Program Files     
  (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modu                                             
  les\read-package-json\node_modules\normalize-package-
  data\lib\fixer.js:281:15)
  npm ERR!     at Object.module.exports.fixNameField (C:\Program Files 
  (x86)\nodejs\node_mo                                             
  dules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\node_modules\normalize-package-
  data\lib\fixer.js                                             :196:5)
  npm ERR!     at C:\Program Files 
  (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-                                             
  json\node_modules\normalize-package-data\lib\normalize.js:29:38
  npm ERR!     at Array.forEach (native)
  npm ERR!     at normalize (C:\Program Files 
  (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\re                                             
  ad-package-json\node_modules\normalize-package-  
  data\lib\normalize.js:28:15)
  npm ERR!     at final (C:\Program Files 
  (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-p                                             
  ackage-json\read-json.js:310:33)
  npm ERR!     at then (C:\Program Files 
  (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-pa                                             
  ckage-json\read-json.js:124:33)
  npm ERR!     at C:\Program Files 
  (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-                                             
  json\read-json.js:284:48
  npm ERR!     at fs.js:207:20
  npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
  npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
  npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
  npm ERR! or email it to:
  npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

  npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
  npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program 
  Files (x86)\\no                                             
  dejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "i" "grunt"
  npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\GEL8953\Dev\MillsDashboard\MillsDashboard
  npm ERR! node -v v0.10.13
  npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.2
```

Comment: have you tried running the command as `su` ?

Comment: no i havent how would i do that i have no familiarity with npm manager or its packages

Comment: what `OS` are you using for this?

Comment: It looks like your package name is invalid. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18200814/npm-not-installing-from-package-json-file-on-windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could need to set the registry:

```
npm set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Uninstall and clean your cache:

```
npm uninstall -g grunt-cli

npm cache clean

npm i -g grunt-cli
```

Downcase the MillsDashboard that contains your bin and controllers.

```
npm i grunt
```

Are you behind a firewall? Proxy?

Comment: i just tried this "npm i -g grunt-cli" and gave same error. im in "Dev/MillsDashboard/MillsDashboard" which is project root directory containing folders "bin, Content, Controllers, Models....etc.." also tried npm i grunt in the same directory and  says a similar error ill edit post to show.

Comment: Edited - definitely downcase that MillsDashboard with your bin and controllers. You can't have a package with capital letters or numbers.

Comment: was a firewall issue. i connected through my phone's hotspot and went in fine.